# HOTP does not generate the same code as from the Google Authenticator

Tags: java, one-time-password, google-authenticator

Currently, I'm struggling with the HOTP implementation in Java for Android. I'm trying to generate an OTP code to match them with the user input to sign in to the app. For that, I use this [script](https://gist.github.com/ibnfirnas/27ff6ae47b2f60ed733c). 
When I create some test values from the moving factor 0 to 19 I get the following codes:

```
106764
867240
658913
270241
373368
105291
051234
812749
615640
648397
846312
825014
565042
820956
757355
372673
964093
451446
360409
```

These codes are all generated from this shared secret which is Base32 encoded: `AECQIBADA3PK3PXP`

When I compare the codes with the generated codes from the Google Authenticator app they are always different. No code from the Google Authenticator app matches one of the them above.

I generated the QR Code with the following URI so I don't know what I'm doing wrong with it:

```
otpauth://hotp/Hash%20based?secret=AECQIBADA3PK3PXP&issuer=Testserver&counter=0&algorithm=SHA1
```

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your system time set at?

Comment: @chrylis I think HOTP does not depend on time, TOTP depends on time.

Comment: @chrylis Exactly it does not depend on the time. HOTP depends on a counter based system. TOTP depends on the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this code with your secret and the generated OTPs are same with Google authenticator.

Call this method with 0<=counter<=100. You will see the results.

```
public static final int[] DIGITS_POWER
        //  0  1   2     3    4        5        6       7         8
        = {1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000};

public String generateHOTP(long count, String seedString) {

    byte[] counter = new byte[8];
    long movingFactor = count;

    for (int i = counter.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        counter[i] = (byte) (movingFactor & 0xff);
        movingFactor >>= 8;
    }

    //from org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base32;

    Base32 base32 = new Base32();
    byte[] seed = base32.decode(seedString);


    byte[] hash = HMAC(seed, counter);
    int offset = hash[hash.length - 1] & 0xf;

    int otpBinary = ((hash[offset] & 0x7f) << 24)
            | ((hash[offset + 1] & 0xff) << 16)
            | ((hash[offset + 2] & 0xff) << 8)
            | (hash[offset + 3] & 0xff);

    int otp = otpBinary % DIGITS_POWER[6];
    String result = Integer.toString(otp);

    while (result.length() < 6) {
        result = "0" + result;
    }
    return result;

}

 private byte[] HMAC(byte[] seed, byte[] counter) {

    try {
        Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        SecretKeySpec macKey = new SecretKeySpec(seed, "RAW");
        hmac.init(macKey);
        return hmac.doFinal(counter);

    } catch (GeneralSecurityException ex) {
        throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, now it works. Thank you so much. You saved my day.

Comment: @Ehsan Why does it only work fine for the key provided in question (AECQIBADA3PK3PXP)? I tried with a different key(QWERTYUIO1PK3PXP) and the results are different from google authenticator.